# PHP DateTime "Fails" with no apparent reason - PHP 7

Tags: php, apache, yii, php-7

I have an extremely weird behaviour in a few of my php7 servers (windows). Please follow me because it's a really weird one.

I have a few windows servers with php 7.0.2 and apache 2.4, both configured correctly. I run a php framework called Yii to render a webapp.

At random intervals (sometimes a day, sometimes a few days, sometimes as little as a few hours) the `dateTime` object of php starts behaving like it's not a `dateTime` anymore.

When I instantiate it with `$var = new DateTime();` it doesn't give any error; However, if I apply any date-related method to it, or even if I try to print it it gives an error that looks like this one:

> [27-Nov-2017 19:48:12 Europe/Rome] PHP Catchable fatal error:  Object
>   of class 8 could not be converted to string in
>   C:\KRIA\htdocs\yii-1.1.18.018a89\framework\db\schema\CDbColumnSchema.php
>   on line 146

The only thing that changes constantly is the class ASCII code displayed.

The incriminated line is this:

```
switch($this->type)
    {
        -->case 'string': return (string)$value;
        case 'integer': return (integer)$value;
        case 'boolean': return (boolean)$value;
        case 'double':
        default: return $value;
    }
```

Nothing fancy, just a cast. But it gets worst: if I put a `print_r`, I get the messed up ASCII value but the type is Object, containing three keys: `date`, `timezone`, `timezone_type`. Exactly like a date object.

But this is really messed up part. If I restart the Apache service, everything gets back to normal.

This is driving me nuts. I've tried countless things but nothing seems to work.

Before blaming Yii, I tried just instantiating a new `DateTime` object and doing both `echo` and `print_r`, with the same result.

What do you guys think? I've never had this problem under CentOS or Debian (with which i usually work).

Is it possible that it's a php version thing?

Thanks a lot

**EDIT AFTER A NEW OCCURENCE OF THE BUG**

Ok, i was (un)lucky enough to catch this bug again. This time the entire system lasted 5 days without showing the behaviour.

I made a few more tests. I've created the simplest php page possible to test this:

```
<?php
 $dt = new DateTime();
 echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

This works as intended. I've then added a print_r($dt), and got:

```
Object ( [date] => 2018-02-02 16:14:30.000000 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => Europe/Rome )
```

Which differs from what i was expecting. The same exact code on my system produces this output:

```
DateTime Object ( [date] => 2018-02-02 16:15:36.000000 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => Europe/Rome )
```

Which is what i was expecting. It seems that the object is no longer recognized as a DateTime obj.

Now, functions like modify or format works, but casting it to string (for example) produces the error shown before.

This application runs on a windows server machine, but the DB is on another one, so i'm able to connect to the latter by different clients.
With my own pc (that produces the "correct" print_r) the system works perfectly. On the faulty one it doesn't work.

The apache config is literally the same.

But now comes the really weird part: on the same machine, after a graceful restart of apache, running the same php code gives me the "correct" output i get on my machine.

It seems to me that there is something that "changes" the background code for the DateTime class in a transient way and completely at random, so when i reboot apache i reset this change and everything goes back to normal.

Last point: i did a clear install of apache and php before the second to last occurrence of this error, just to avoid any file corruption problem.

Is it possible that there is some external factor or something like that that screws me at random intervals?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You will probably have to provide one coherent piece of code which shows this behaviour, instead of some disconnected snippets with ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ in-between.

Comment: It is unlikely that the same thing behaves differently from time to time - it's the nature of programcode that it does the same thing every time. The DateTime object might not be the cause for your problem.

Comment: OK, if you've factored out Yii being a contributing factor, then don't clutter up your question and tagging with it. Have you got a complete stand-alone example that demonstrates what you're seeing, with out any other external dependencies? If you have: post that instead. If you haven't: that's what you should currently be working towards. Reading: sscce.org

Comment: Hi, you are all right. This is the most in-dept i could've gotten atm. We are talking about production systems that needs to be up in order to produce money. After two days of downtime i realized that, in any webpage i open, when i do a new DateTime() i get that error. I will try to do a standalone php page loading nothing as soon as i get the chance

Comment: a few things you get the above mentioned error when you try to use the format or any other date function using `dateObject` and not when you insert data to the table?

Comment: I get the error when i try to convert to string, either via casting or via internal methods (that doesn't exists because it's not recognized as a DateTime format) and then i use any date-manipulating method, e.g. add one day.
I don't reach the db writing part because it requires a casting...

Comment: No new ideas guys?

Answer (score 0):

After a few months of suffering, i found a solution not to the cause underneath but to the sympthom at least.

The problem is some kind of component, hidden in all the different review made by god knows who (it's kinda of a messy organization) that corrupts the memory. Following this you get the error, sometimes accompanied by a "zend_heap memory corrupted", sometimes no.

Enabling the mod_fcgi in apache solves the problem. Following the logs I learned that this way the container is able to shut down any problematic php thread.

I hope this helps someone else!